# Multiple sites/virtual hosts not working consistently

Tags: virtualbox, 14.04, apache2

I'm not really sure what information will help getting an answer to this so I'm going to try a minimal approach. Please ask for info that would be helpful.

I successfully have 3 Drupal sites running on my local dev machine but what made them work is a mystery.

I followed http://klau.si/dev to get the first site up and then installed 2 more. When I first tried to access the 2nd site I kept getting the Apache default page instead of the Drupal site. I then added a second 'Listen' line to ports.conf and the site started working. So in ports.conf I had:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
Listen 127.0.0.2:80
```

I thought this was the answer until I tried to get the 3rd site working and I did not need to add an additional `Listen` to do so. The 3rd site initially did not work, it could not be found. I edited `ports.conf`, `apache2.conf` and `hosts.conf` in an organized way trying to figure out what would make it work but found no pattern. When the site finally started to work it just seemed like magic. From hours of working on this it seems to me there is some config that is not getting refreshed/read into memory and when I make some edit it does and the site starts working.

So some specific questions to this:

1. After editing `/etc/hosts`, `sitename.conf`, `apache2.conf` and `ports.conf`, run `a2ensite` and then restart Apache, is there anything else that needs to be done to be sure all new configuration is loaded?
2. I'm confused with the hosts file. Should I have all sites on the same IP address like 
   this:

   ```
   127.0.0.1   localhost
   127.0.1.1   Ubuntu-05
   127.0.0.1   drupal-8.localhost
   127.0.0.1   drupal-7-site01.localhost
   127.0.0.1   drupal-7-site02.localhost
   ```

or should they have different IP addresses like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Ubuntu-05
127.0.0.1   drupal-8.localhost
127.0.0.2   drupal-7-site01.localhost
127.0.0.3   drupal-7-site02.localhost
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you may have. (running on Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the tutorial you used was for creating local development environment on a Linux host machine and not using a virtual environment.

I ran into the same problem using Virtualbox. You shouldn't have to mess with the ports.conf file.  In Ubuntu 14.04, your virtual host file names must end in .conf, so in your /etc/apache2/sites-available directory you should have:

- drupal-8.localhost.conf
- drupal-7-site01.localhost.conf
- drupal-7-site02.localhost.conf

Enable each site by running:

```
$ sudo a2ensite drupal-8.localhost.conf
$ sudo a2ensite drupal-7-site01.localhost.conf
$ sudo a2ensite drupal-7-site01.localhost.conf
```

If you are running Virtualbox as a server from a host machine (such as Mac), you likely have an IP address on your local network for your Virtualbox server.  Your server's IP address will display on the welcome page when you SSH into your Virtualbox server.  If you're already logged in, you can obtain your IP address by running:

```
$ ifconfig
```

Your IP might be something like 192.168.57.100.

Since these are not real domain names with full DNS, you will need to add each one to your host machine's host files. (On Mac this is /etc/hosts).  So your host file would look like:

```
127.0.0.1         localhost
192.168.57.100    drupal-8.localhost
192.168.57.100    drupal-7-site01.localhost
192.168.57.100    drupal-7-site02.localhost
```

When you enter a domain name into a web browser such as google.com, your system looks at its host file (on Mac it's /etc/hosts) to resolve the domain.  If the domain is not there, it goes out to the Internet to start resolving the domain name to find the proper server IP.  You can override that process by adding custom lines to the host file.  For example, if you added the following line to your host file:

```
192.168.57.100    google.com
```

Whenever you typed google.com into your address bar, it would redirect to your Virtualbox server instead of the real google.com site.

So, when you're working in a virtual test environment, you'll need to add each test site to your /etc/hosts file.  There may be a way to configure your test server so you don't have to add a separate entry for each site in your hosts file, but I haven't gone that far.

As a side note, rather than naming your sites with .localhost, you might consider using .dev instead.  It's shorter, and more closely resembles a real domain name.  Generally localhost is used when you're referencing something on the same machine (i.e. connecting to a database on the same server, or developing locally on your host machine - such as running apache/php/mysql/ruby directly on your Mac/Windows machine). When you run Ubuntu in Virtualbox, you're running a completely separate environment from your host machine.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. As mentioned, I'm running Ubuntu in VirtualBox. The host machine is Windows 8. Apache is running on the Ubuntu machine which led me to believe the correct ip address for the hosts file is 127.0.0.1. Running ifconfig, eth0=10.0.2.15 and lo=127.0.0.1. Given Apache is on the the same machine as the Drupal sites (i.e., Apache & Drupal sites are all running in the Ubuntu guest) should I still be using 10.0.2.15. - thanks again.